# JSTL in Struts tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I have to check a condition in struts tag and enable or disable the field as follows:

```
<c:when test="${multipleCase=='true'}">
    <html:text property="${row.dataElementJavaName}" 
               maxlength="${row.dataElementSize}" 
               size="60" 
               value="${row.dataElementValue}"
               onkeyup="javascript:enableSave()" 
               onkeypress="return letternumber(event,'c')" 
               <c:if test="${model.readonlyStatus=='true'}">disabled</c:if> 
    />        
</c:when>
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
Attribute: <c:if is not a valid attribute name
Encountered end tag </c:if> without corresponding start tag.
```

If i use the same in an HTML input field it works fine. What is the other option? any inputs?

Comment: Which version of struts and which version of jstl are you using? Also which servlet api version are you using?

Comment: you want to set attribute disabled = true on some condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just place the `<c:if>` tag within the `<html:text>` tag declaration. It only supports attributes such as defined [here](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/userGuide/struts-html.html#text).

That's why there's an error complaining about the `<c:if` attribute not being valid. It's treating it as if it were another attribute, which doesn't exist. So I think what you're trying in your code is just not possible.

As you mentioned, including the `<c:if>` in HTML would work fine. I'd expect it would look something like this:

```
...
<input type="text" name="${row.dataElementJavaName}" 
           maxlength="${row.dataElementSize}" 
           size="60" 
           value="${row.dataElementValue}"
           onkeyup="javascript:enableSave()" 
           onkeypress="return letternumber(event,'c')" 
           <c:if test="${model.readonlyStatus=='true'}">disabled</c:if> 
/>  
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<c:if>` outside the `<html:text>` like this:

```
<c:when test="${multipleCase=='true'}">
  <c:if test="${model.readonlyStatus=='true'}">
    <html:text property="${row.dataElementJavaName}" 
               maxlength="${row.dataElementSize}" 
               size="60" 
               value="${row.dataElementValue}"
               onkeyup="javascript:enableSave()" 
               onkeypress="return letternumber(event,'c')" 
               disabled
    />   
  </c:if>     
  <c:if test="${model.readonlyStatus!='true'}">
    <html:text property="${row.dataElementJavaName}" 
               maxlength="${row.dataElementSize}" 
               size="60" 
               value="${row.dataElementValue}"
               onkeyup="javascript:enableSave()" 
               onkeypress="return letternumber(event,'c')" 
    />   
  </c:if>     
</c:when>
```